# Type cast hardcoded value to volatile UINT8 pointer - C programming

Tags: c

```
#define MMIO_READ8(Address)                 (*(volatile UINT8 *)(Address))

Data8 = MMIO_READ8(0xFCE00000); // 0xFCE0000 is memory map address space
```

I am using Mircosoft compiler (MSVC) and get the warning below. We set warning as error in compiler flag so I need help for the resolution of this waring.

warning C4306: 'type cast' : conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'volatile UINT8
*' of greater size

Comment: 32 bit machine or 64 bit? If 32 bit,  the size of the pointer is 4 bytes, so you can ignore the warning

Answer (score 3):

[According to the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s11t648.aspx) this happens because the target type (a pointer) is larger than the source type (`unsigned int`). I suppose you're doing a 64bit build which means that the `unsigned int` is 4 bytes and the pointer is 8 bytes.

The MSDN page also explains that in this case, the uppper bits of the target value (e.g. the uppper 32bit) are zeroed out, which is probably what you want.

To silence this warning, you could adjust the macro so that you first cast to a sufficiently large integer type before casting to a pointer. E.g. try

```
  #define MMIO_READ8(Address) (*(volatile UINT8 *)(intptr_t)(Address))
```